# Struts2: Unable to set multiple default selections for struts select tag

Tags: jakarta-ee, struts2

```
<s:select  name="carTypeIds"
           list="carTypes"
           listKey="carTypeId" 
           id="selectTypes"
           key="carTypeId" size="4"
           listValue="name"
           headerKey=""
           headerValue="All"
           multiple="true"
           value="%{carTypeIds}"
           label="Car Types"
/>
```

Here **carTypes** is list of type **Car** containing properties **carTypeId (long)** and **name (String)**.

**carTypeIds** is a **String** array containing carTypeIds which I want to select by default. Why is it not working? when I do

```
<s:property value="%{carTypeIds}" />
```

I am able to print the carTypeIds.
New to struts, any help would be appriciated.

Comment: Also ensure you have all the getters and setters you need... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems fine, except that for the `key` attribute: it is used to preset `name`, `value` and `label` attributes all in once, all with the same value. Since you need different values and have already preset them, remove the `key` attribute. From [the docs](https://struts.apache.org/docs/select.html):

> **key**   : Set the key (name, value, label) for this particular component

Also ensure your `carTypeIds` contains the same type of object of your key, or the equals might fail (eg `Long` vs `int`):

> **multiple** : Creates a multiple select. The tag will pre-select multiple values if the values are passed as an Array or a Collection(of appropriate types) via the value attribute. If one of the keys equals one of the values in the Collection or Array it wil be selected

P.S: note that the `headerKey` should not be blank...

Comment: Removed the **key**  attribute, still not working! Is it because carTypeIds(value)  is String array and carTypeId(listKey) is long?

Comment: @Abhijeet: Yes, it is because of type mismatch. Change your  `carTypeIds(value)` to collection of long-s and it should work.

Comment: @Abhijeet yes, as I've written in the answer : ensure they are of the same type

Comment: Yes it worked on changing the type to **long**. Thank you Superman :) :) !!